# Entity Framework, generic List

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4

I have a question about generic list.

Assume that I have a database which contains three tables, User table, Order table and Item table.

In the C# code, I want a function, called GetList to get all he records from one of the three tables.

If I don't use generic method, I have to create 3 different methods which looks like GetAllUsers(), GetAllOrders() and GetAllItems(). Inside these 3 methods, I will have to write the linq to query the database.

My question is how do I implement a generic method.

I want to use EF 4.1. I know how to do it by using NHibrate tho.

**UPDATE**

What about this? I found it from another post, it can be used to get one single record

```
        public T GetSingleEntity<T>(Expression<Func<T,bool>> expression) where T:class
    {
        using (PersonalLinksEntities dbContext = new PersonalLinksEntities()) 
        {
            return dbContext.CreateObjectSet<T>().SingleOrDefault(expression);
        }

    }
```

PersonalLinksEntities is generated by EF, it is database first model.

**Here is how I call this method**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var thisOne = base.GetSingleEntity<PersonalRecord>(r=>r.RecordID==1);            
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific implementation going to depend on what you are using to access your data.  NHib, EF, L2S?  These all have some way of accessing an  IQueryable generically.

You could expose a method such as:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetQueryable<T>()
{
   //Implementation depends on your data provider
   //return dataContext.GetTable<T>();
   //return session.Query<T>();
}
```

But probably what you want to do is follow a repository pattern with a different repository for each type.  But you can use an abstract base repository that accepts a type parameter and is reusable.

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T>
{
   public IQueryable<T> GetQuery()
   {
     //Implementation determined by provider
    }

}
```

Comment: The funny thing is, since my dbContext is generated by EF automatically (Database first), I don't even have a method called .GetTable()... that is why I am trying to find a alt way.

Comment: //return session.Query<T>(); That is NHibrate, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, just popped in a couple of examples...I'm more of an NHIb guy than EF.  It's just better in a lot of ways.

Comment: Your update is correct for EF DB first:  context.CreateObjectSet<T>()

Comment: ah, cool, now i just need to know how to call it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As there are no details in the question regarding what you have written already. If you just want to GET ALL RECORDS from the tables...Why LINQ...?? You can simply query the database using Data-set and Data-adapter in a method and to make that generic you just pass the table name and get back a Data-set, after that you can play with that Data-set as you like. Please elaborate more if there is any specific complexity in this case which I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

There already exists the method you want on DbContext called Set, e.g. var results = dbContext.Set();

If you are using ObjectContext then the method you want is CreateObjectSet().